# Environments in GitHub Actions incompatible with reusable workflows?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

I have the following job

```
  build-and-push-docker-image:
    name: Build and push docker image
    if: github.repository == 'Org/repo'
    uses: Org/repo/.github/workflows/reusable.yaml@main
    with:
      dockerfile: My_Dockerfile
    environment:
      name: Production
    needs:
      - job-1
      - job-2
    secrets:
      SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.SECRET_1 }}
```

This fails the basic syntax checking as follows:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/my_workflow.yml (Line: 236, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'environment'

Why is that?

Comment: maybe just `env` for environment variables https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-setting-an-environment-variable

Comment: This is for the GHA [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) where the specific job is supposed to run on, not for env vars

Comment: from the doc seems should put at `job` level

Comment: Isn't it already at `job` level? `build-and-push-docker-image` is a `job` block that invokes a reusable workflow

Comment: from the linter `when a reusable workflow is called with "uses", "environment" is not available.`

Comment: Thanks. Where did you spot that message if I may ask?

Comment: oh sure! `actionlint`, see https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint there is also an online version https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of it in the docs; but, in the [official example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) the called workflow has the `environment` configured but its caller does not.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, it is not possible to use `environment` with a reusable workflow. You would have to define it within the reusable workflow.

See here: [Supported keywords for jobs that call a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#supported-keywords-for-jobs-that-call-a-reusable-workflow)

Comment: Saved my day. This should be referenced when you go through the `vars` context docs... wasted some time on this. Thanks!